# How to duplicate a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Basically I need to duplicate a `JPanel`, for example if we do it with `Integer` variables this should work:

```
Integer intaux,int1;
int1 = 3;
intaux = int1;
```

But this doesn't work with panels:

```
jPanelaux = jPanel1;
```

Is there any setter method I don't know?

Comment: *"Basically I need to duplicate a JPanel.."*  Why?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: `jPanelaux = jPanel1;` doesn't create another instance of jpanel, it just gives you another reference to the same object.

Comment: `intaux = int1;` does **not** create a duplicate Integer instance; it just creates another reference to the existing int1. A duplicate **can** be created using `intaux = new Integer(int1);`

Answer (score 1):

As Kira San already said, you will need an instance for every panel you want to display.

For example:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    //creates a JPanel with the text "hello"
    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        this.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
    }
}

public class someClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

        //here we add the same instance of MyPanel twice to panel1, which ..
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        //...adds myPanel
        panel1.add(myPanel);
        //...removes myPanel from the container it was added to first and adds it to this container (which is panel1 in both cases)
        panel1.add(myPanel);

        //here we add two separate instances of MyPanel to panel2, which should both be shown
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new MyPanel());
        panel2.add(new MyPanel());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your own JPanel child class that contains all you want.
Something like:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    JButton okButton;
    JButton cancelButton;
    JTextField nameTextField;

    public MyPanel() {
         okButton = new JButton();
         JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");

         setLayOut(...);
         add(okButton);
         ...
    }
}
```

Either you use a GUI editor, or copy all from your current code.

Then you can use two `new MyPanel()`s to have identical complex components.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a duplicate image of the original panel then creating another JPanel that uses the original JPanel to paint could work.

```
JPanel dup = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        jPanel1.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return jPanel1.getPreferredSize();
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize(){
        return jPanel1.getMaximumSize();
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
        return jPanel1.getMinimumSize();
    }
};
```

This would only create a view of the original panel and none of the components would be functional, eg JButton or JTextField would not receive input.There would also need to be some work done to cause repainting.

Comment: *"I really see no reason why this should get downvoted."*  Then perhaps you should refrain from trying to answer Swing based questions.  This approach will not work for things like text fields and buttons added to the original panel.  It recreates an image of the original panel, but without any functionality.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the original question doesn't say anything about making input fields and buttons functional. It doesn't say anything at all really. I realize what this solution does, and I state it at the top.

Comment: *"It doesn't say anything at all really."*  Which is a good hint to request, and wait for, more details.  Offering half-baked solutions doesn't really help in the bigger scheme of things.  Your -1 (now -2) is well earned.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Rather than addressing a question you launch a personal attack.  _"Then perhaps you should refrain from trying to answer Swing based questions."_  That is unnecessary. You claim the approach will not work because it is only an image of the original panel. That might not address what the OP wants, but it could be an answer to "How to duplicate a JPanel?"